# Why AspectJ doesn't catch event?

Tags: java, gradle, testing, aspectj

I'm trying to launch a simple example of AspectJ code inside the Gradle project.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id "io.freefair.aspectj" version "5.1.1"
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/aspectj']
    }
  }

  test {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
  testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
  testImplementation group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.23.1'
  testImplementation group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.9.6'
  implementation group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.9.6'
  implementation group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.9.6'
  testImplementation group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.9.6'
  testImplementation group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest', version: '2.2'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

In the folder 'src/main/aspectj' class org.example.aspectj.DemoAspect

```java
package org.example.aspectj;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class DemoAspect {
  @Before("execution(* *(..)) && !within(org.example.aspectj.DemoAspect)")
  public void logEnter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("!!!!!!DemoAspect");
    System.out.print(joinPoint.getStaticPart());
    System.out.print(" -> ");
    System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature());
  }
}
```

In the folder 'src/main/java' class org.example.aspectj.Main

```java
package org.example.aspectj;

import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("new Date() -> " + new Date());
  }
}
```

I'm running `Main` class. Code from `DemoAspect` was not called. What is wrong in configuration?

Comment: I do not understand the close votes. This is a fully reproducible sample including Gradle build file.

Comment: Excuse me, what you mean saying "the close votes"? This code does not work as expected.

Comment: This question was closed for the reason "needs more details", before I commented and voted to reopen on your behalf. Now, after 3 reopen votes, since 3 hours ago it is open for answers again. I am busy now, but will answer tomorrow.

Comment: Could you please explain the doctrine: "the close votes"? I'm not aware of it at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, search for "close". Users with enough reputation points can vote to close a question, so it does not receive any more answers until the author has edited and improved her low-quality or off-topic question to better conform to the community standards. Then, others can vote to reopen it. Only open questions can be answered. Previously, your question was closed due to its lack of detail.

Comment: I will look for other sites to be asking questions. Your site has become very uncomfortable to use. You can be closing and blocking yourself further.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not "my site". I am a normal user, just like you, a volunteer helping other community members for free. But as a new community member anywhere, be it online or in the regular offline world, you always need to get to know the community rules. Moving to another place simply means, that you need to learn other rules elsewhere. If that is too much for you, you should not ask for help in any community. It is normal that you should stay on topic and also to make it as easy as possible for others to help you by making your problem reproducible.

Comment: In any community, it is give and take. You took my answere here, but neither accepted nor upvoted it. You asked a follow-up question which I also already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78186665/1082681), despite you not having accepted my correct answer here. I think, you ought to think about your own attitude.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the old plugin version 5.1.1 you are using and Gradle 6.6.1. If the aspect is in *src/main/aspectj* and the application class in *src/main/java*, the AspectJ compiler (Ajc) says:

```
[warning] advice defined in org.example.aspectj.DemoAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
```

Moving everything to *src/main/aspectj* makes it work.

I suggest upgrading to the latest Freefair plugin version 8.6. It now does not need *src/main/aspectj* anymore (even though it still recognises it and you can put your aspects there), but you can put everything into *src/main/java*, which is more convenient and also in line with how AspectJ Maven Plugin does it. You may also want to upgrade to AspectJ 1.9.21.2, which still supports older compilation targets like Java 8, but also up to Java 21. Just make sure to run the build on JDK 17+. Your program can then run on an older JRE, depending on `targetCompatibility`.

```java
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'io.freefair.aspectj' version '8.6'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

java {
  sourceCompatibility = '8'
  targetCompatibility = '8'
}

dependencies {
  implementation group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.9.21.2'
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Please note that you only need a dependency on `aspectjrt` in your project. The plugin will figure out which compiler version to use on its own.

```java
package org.example.aspectj;

import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("new Date() -> " + new Date());
  }
}
```

I also simplified your log output a bit, simply logging the join point instead of making method calls on it.

```java
package org.example.aspectj;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class DemoAspect {
  @Before("execution(* *(..)) && !within(org.example.aspectj.DemoAspect)")
  public void logEnter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
  }
}
```

Running the build on Gradle 8.4 and JDK 17 or 21 and then the main class yields:

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 154 ms
> Task :compileJava SKIPPED
> Task :compileAspectj
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes

> Task :Main.main()
execution(void org.example.aspectj.Main.main(String[]))
new Date() -> Sun Mar 17 09:16:09 CET 2024
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, several times such a message appeared for some conditions. That was the second question which I planned to ask. That is, sometimes aspect does not respond at all, it writes this message.

Comment: Thank you, @kriegaex. Now it works. Gradle should be upgraded to 8.6. 
But this code doesn't work properly still:

Comment: Then please, accept (click on the grey check mark beside the answer, turning it green) and upvote (click on the arrow up symbol) the answer. That is the best way to thank people on SO and signals to others that the answer has been accepted by the author.