# How to replace standard call to System.currentTimeMillis() via AspectJ?

Tags: java, time, system, aspectj

I'm trying to replace System.currentTimeMillis() with own value. It's needed for test cases.
Code example:

```java
package org.example.aspectj;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class TimeAspect
{
    @Around("execution(public static native long currentTimeMillis())")
    public long changeCallsToCurrentTimeInMillisMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example.aspectj;

public class TimeDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("currentTimeMillis -> " + currentTimeMillis);
    }
}
```

```
[warning] advice defined in org.example.aspectj.TimeAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
```

A see answer:

```
Task :TimeDemo.main()
  currentTimeMillis -> 1710770641050
```

So the time is not changed.
What is wrong?

Comment: Don't try to do it like that. Make a `TimeService` which you mock in your tests.

Comment: To whoever voted to close the question: Please refrain from voting if you do not understand AspectJ or simply dislike the approach the OP takes to mock a timestamp. Even though I agree that there are better ways to do this, the question contains enough information to reproduce the problem and also to answer it with regard to AspectJ, see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot weave aspects into JDK classes by conventional means, and I am not going to elaborate on advanced use cases for JDK weaving here.

The simple solution is to weave the aspect into your application code instead, because that is what you control during compilation. Simply use `call` instead of `execution` in order to weave into the *calling* code instead of the *called* code.

```java
@Around("call(public static native long currentTimeMillis())")
```

Console log after the change:

```
currentTimeMillis -> 0
```